# 'this' is undefined in react for adding checkbox events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered error in react wherein `this` is undefined. This is my first time developing a react application.

In UI, it says `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` while in console the value of `this` is undefined.

Thank you for your help.

Here is the existing code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
//import makeData from "../makeData";
import { useTableState } from "react-table";

import { Button } from "../Styles";
import Table from "../TransactionPanelTable";

// Simulate a server
const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

  // Ideally, you would pass this info to the server, but we'll do it here for convenience
  const filtersArr = Object.entries(filters);

  // Get our base data
  let rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rows.push({
      transaction_seq: 1234,
      rec_count: 1234,
      user_id: "test",
      updated_at: "",
      duration: 1.23
    });
  }

  // Apply Filters
  if (filtersArr.length) {
    rows = rows.filter(row =>
      filtersArr.every(([key, value]) => row[key].includes(value))
    );
  }

  // Apply Sorting
  if (sortBy.length) {
    const [{ id, desc }] = sortBy;
    rows = [...rows].sort(
      (a, b) => (a[id] > b[id] ? 1 : a[id] === b[id] ? 0 : -1) * (desc ? -1 : 1)
    );
  }

  // Get page counts
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(rows.length / pageSize);
  const rowStart = pageSize * pageIndex;
  const rowEnd = rowStart + pageSize;

  // Get the current page
  rows = rows.slice(rowStart, rowEnd);

  let checkedMap = new Map();
  rows.forEach(row => checkedMap.set(row, false)); //preset each to false, ideally w/ a key instead of the entire row
  this.setState({ checkedMap: checkedMap });

  //handleCheckedChange(row) {
  //  let modifiedMap = this.state.checkedMap;
  //  modifiedMap.set(row, !this.state.checkedMap.get(row));
  //  this.setState({ checkedMap: modifiedMap });
  //}

  return {
    rows,
    pageCount
  };
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are here to help other users when they experience problems to point them in the right direction. We are not here to fix your bugs are write new code for you. Try to google why you get a Type Error. What did you try to fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

'this' is undefined because you haven't bounded the context of the component to the method.
As you are new to react, i would suggest you to go through concepts like bind,es6 and other js lingos so that you can code better and avoid such errors.

In this case you need to bind the context either by using bind method or by using es6 arrow functions which are class functions.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in constructor function where you are calling this **getServerData** function.

getServerData = getServerData.bind(this);

Here  bind will return new method which will set context (this) to your calling class.

It is preferable to set state in class with in that promise resolved function.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's answer your question. `this` is `undefined` because you are using ES6 modules **and** you are using an arrow function `const getServerData = async (...) => {`.

- Inside arrow functions, the *this* binding is not dynamic, but is instead lexical. That means that *this* actually refers to the originating context (outside your arrow function).
- In a basic js script, that would point to the `Window` global context. But you are using ES6 module, with *import* statements. One of the goals of ES6 modules is to isolate code. So inside such a module, there is no default access to a global `Window` context, so your *this* end up being `undefined`.

Now, several misconceptions are recognizable in your code.

1. writing an ES6 modules, you should have an export statement somewhere inside in order to consume it outside.
2. The request to a server should preferably be isolated in another function, so that the structure of your component will be more easy to apprehend, especially if you are learning React.
3. Read the [very good React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) to understand the basics of it.

   - You should not use `async` when defining a React functional component
   - Since you have no state defined in your component (importing `useState` is not enough, you must use it: [State Hooks doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook)), you cannot use `setState`.
   - `this.setState` refer to using [React class syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to define your component, `useState` refer to using State Hooks. You cannot do both in a same component. You have to choose.

So to sum-up, your `getServerData` function should be outside of your Component and should not have to do anything with state management. And you should build a React component that will call your function in a lifecycle method.

Stay confident, you will get it sooner than you think! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this.getServerData = this.getServerData.bind(this);